# How to determine the order of a pole of a function like $\frac{\sin z}{1 - \cos z}$ for residue calculation?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am asked to determine the residue of the function defined by $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{1 - \cos z}$ at the point $z_0 = 0$. I am comfortable with using the formula:$$
  \text{Res} = \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \partial^{m-1}\left( (z - z_0)^{m-1} f(z) \right)|_{z = z_0}
$$ where $m$ is the order of the pole at $z_0$, however I am struggling with finding the order of this pole.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to find the order in advance; it'll be the first $m$ for which that formula works! (Note, though, that you're missing a power of $m$ on $(z-z_0)$.)

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, near $0$,$$\frac{\sin z}{1-\cos z}=\frac{z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots}{\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{z^4}{4!}+\cdots}=\frac1z\times\frac{1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\cdots}{\frac1{2!}-\frac{z^2}{4!}+\cdots},$$you have a pole of order $1$ at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The power series for $\cos z$ at $0$ is $\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^{n-1}z^{2n}/(2n)!$.  This implies that $1-\cos z=z^2\cdot(h(z))$ for holomorphic $h$ such that $h(0)=1/2$.  Thus it is a simple pole, since $\sin z=z\cdot(g(z))$ where $g$ is holomorphic and $g(0)=1$.  The residue is $g(0)/h(0)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(z)$, the order of a pole at $z=a$ is the least positive integer $m$ such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^mf(z)$ is finite. In your case

$\lim_{z\rightarrow0}z.\frac{\sin z}{1-\cos z}=1$ after applying L-Hopital's rule twice.